# Xcode 12 is not asking for Local Network permissions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, printing, xcode12, local-network

I have built one application which has a facility to print sticker using brother printer. When I run application using Xcode 11.3.1 it is asking for Local Network permission and also provides search result with available printer(WiFi Printer. QL-820NWB) in local network. But when I run same code using Xcode 12.0.1 it is not asking for Local Network permission and also not showing me results on same device(After removing previous installation by Xcode 11.3.1).

Currently I am using brother printer latest SDK to connect printer.

I have tried this multiple times. Also restarted device and Xcode but no luck.
Any suggestions? What I am missing in latest Xcode versions?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your plist refer attached.

Thanks[!plist[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsTKA.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsTKA.png)